# C program won't communicate with Arduino unless I first use Arduino serial monitor or PuTTY

Tags: c, arduino

I've written a program in C that prints data from my Arduino micro to terminal. My problem is that when I first connect the Arduino to my Windows PC it won't work with my program until I first use program like Arduino IDE Serial Monitor or PuTTY. After that it works fine until I disconnect  and reconnect the USB.

My C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    float val;
    int jori;
    char buff[1];
    DWORD dwRead, dwWrite;
    DCB dcb = {sizeof dcb};
    HANDLE hComm;
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    char port[8];
    printf("Give port (COM#):\n");
    gets(port);
    hComm = CreateFile (port,
                        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                        0,
                        0,
                        OPEN_EXISTING,
                        0,
                        0);
    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("INVALID HANDLE VALUE\n");
        main();
    }
    //if (GetCommState(hComm, &dcb)){
    //    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    //    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    //    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    //    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    //    printf("DCB ON\n");
    //}
    dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
    dcb.BaudRate = 9600;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    do {
        ReadFile(hComm, buff, sizeof(buff), &dwRead, NULL);
        if (dwRead){
            WriteFile(screen, buff, sizeof(buff), &dwWrite, NULL);
            //val = atof(buff);
            //printf("\r%f",val);
        }}
        while ( jori != 66);
        return 0;
}
```

And Arduino code:

```
int i = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
 Serial.println(i);
  i = i + 1;
  delay(1000);
}
```

EDIT: I have fixed the problem.

I had to add

```
if (!EscapeCommFunction(hComm, CLRDTR)){
        LocalFree(NULL);
}
if (!EscapeCommFunction(hComm, SETDTR)){
        LocalFree(NULL);
}
```

before setting my dcb

Comment: I am not familiar with Arduino programming, but calling `main()` in the middle of the `main()` function seems odd.  ( `if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("INVALID HANDLE VALUE\n");
        main();` )   I

Comment: When you plug Arduino USB cable into windows PC, it will show up as a serial port.  (Use [device manager](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=device+manager+windows+10) to see what port has been instantiated, or note what COM port PuTTY is using when it connects).   Then open that port in your code.  There is non-Arduino specific [example code here](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J73/15.6) that may give some insight.  Make sure you disconnect from PuTTY, or your IDE Serial Monitor before trying to run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you could try.

1. Check if you have to enable the DTR (data-terminal-ready) flow control in your console program.
2. Check if you have to wait (only few milli seconds) after opening the serial port in your console program before accessing the serial port.

Comment: This isn't an actual answer.

Comment: Agree, but I can't use comments (not enough reputation) and I had a similar problem and wanted to offer my help.